# Hybris: What is the best way to manage data-smartedit-allow-origin (in index.html) for different environments if the application is hosted in CCV2?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

What is the best way to manage `data-smartedit-allow-origin` (in index.html) for different environments if the application is hosted in CCV2? Currently, the value is hardcoded in index.html. For our Development Storefront, it's pointing to Development SmartEdit/Hybris. e.g. data-smartedit-allow-origin="Development-URL"

How about if we have other environments like Staging and Production environments? We are thinking of combining them into 1, like: data-smartedit-allow-origin="Development-URL,Staging-URL,Production-URL" But, this doesn't seem ideal. For Hybris, we can have different local.properties files for different environments. (e.g. local-dev.properties, local.prod.properties)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current suggestion from the Spartacus Team is "to have a consistent list of wildcard values, that apply across dev/staging/prod". e.g. data-smartedit-allow-origin="*.company.com" . This means a Development storefront can allow SmartEdit of other environments.

References:

- Slack: https://spartacus-storefront.slack.com/archives/CD16V16FR/p1588390296420900
- Slack: https://spartacus-storefront.slack.com/archives/CD16V16FR/p1587558947291000
- SmartEdit Setup Instructions for Spartacus: https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/smartEdit-setup-instructions-for-spartacus/
- Whitelisting SmartEdit for Your Storefront: https://help.sap.com/viewer/86dd1373053a4c2da8f9885cc9fbe55d/1905/en-US/fb742b29cf3c4e81aac7c131c0441172.html